# SQL OR statement does not work in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to get some elements from a database (phpmyadmin). The database "top" is set up like:

---

```
ID  || Name
____________
1   || Home

2   || About

3   || Users

4   || Admin

...
```

I use the following Code to get the information:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT ID
            FROM top
            WHERE Name='Users' OR Name='Admin'";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql); 
    $oq = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    if(in_array($_GET['ID'], $oq)){
     //Execute some Code
    }
?>
```

If I execute the sql-code I get the result I want (ID 3 and 4) but in "$oq" there is only one element (the first one -> 3) left. Therefore the Code I want to execute is only displayed once.

Comment: So `fetch` all records at once, of fetch records in a loop.

Comment: Because [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns 2 rows and [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) reads only the first one. You have to either call [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) in a loop or use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) if possible.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() reads 1 row each time, you should call it several times to read all rows returned by SQL query. But, you can simply filter the rows in your query, "... WHERE Name IN ('Users', 'Admin') AND ID = $_GET['ID']".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a while loop:

```
$oq = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['ID'];
    $oq[] = $row['ID'];
}
```

As you have done it you're only fetching one row in `$oq`. You will have to add each value to the array `$oq` in order to use `in_array()` for the test.

There are some other techniques you can use here, for instance you could  fetch everything (an array of arrays) and loop through the array, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use array to use have multiple DB values

```
 $values=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 $values = array('ID'=>$row['ID']);

 }
```